# PHP Mailer not sending to recipient, but sending to form filler ok

Tags: php, ajax, email, phpmailer

I have been ripping my hair out trying to resolve this issue and after days of trying it's now time to ask for some help.

Basically I have a form that I have adapted from [this script](http://www.smarttutorials.net/send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-without-refrshing-a-page/).

Now, the form is functioning almost correctly, just a few tweaks on my part. But when I test the form it sends to the person sending the form, but it does not send to me.

I have checked with the host and everything is functioning on their end, so I see it as a script issue. I'm an absolute novice when it comes to PHP and Javascript, so I'm hoping somebody can assist me in rectifying this issue. I'm not sure whether it is in the `mail.php`, my form page or the `class.phpmailer.php` file.

This is the code in the mail.php file:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = I used the correct port number here;                    // set the SMTP server port
    //$mail->Host       = "mysmtpserverhost"; // SMTP server
    //$mail->Username   = "me@myemail.com";     // SMTP server username
    //$mail->Password   = "mypassword";            // SMTP server password
    $mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail
    $mail->addReplyTo("me@myemail.com");
    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :

```
$mail->addReplyTo("me@myemail.com")
```

To :

```
$mail->addAddress("me@myemail.com", '');
```

Difference between those two :

```
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
```

[This](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) link will be helpful for you.

Comment: You should be able to send an email wherever you want to, even yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that problem has now be solved... I had the email address with "...." instead of '....' so that is now fixed.. again thanks for your help :)